# How can I sleep() parallely inside asyncio task if parent function isn't async?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio, sleep

**CODE:**

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        # some of the code
        ...
        ...
        xxx.add_handler(self.event_handler, event_xyz)
        asyncio.create_task(self.keep_alive())
        xxx.run_until_disconnected()

    def keep_alive(self):
        # stuff to keep connection alive
        ...
        ...
        time.sleep(5) # this will block whole script
        asyncio.sleep(5) # this won't work because of lack of async on _init_ and keep_alive
    
    async def event_handler(self):
        await stuff
    
    # other functions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```

The part of the code that keeps the connection alive has api limits. So, I need to have the `sleep` statement inside `keep_alive()` function.

I understand that the design of the code can be completely changed to make it work but it is a big script and everything else is working perfectly. So, preferable is if this could be made to work.
I'm open to using anything else like threads as long as rest of the code isn't getting blocked during the `sleep`.

Comment: Do you have an ansycio event loop at all in your code, or would this be the only async stuff you'd need?

Comment: @Blckknght updated the code with the event_handler part which it is async function.

Answer (score -1):

This is a straightforward situation.  `time.sleep` *will* block the current thread, including the asyncio event loop for that thread (if there is one).  Period.  Case closed.

If your API requires you to have time.sleep calls, and your program must do something while the current thread is sleeping, then asyncio is not the solution.  That doesn't mean that asyncio cannot be used for other threads or other purposes within your program design, but it absolutely can't run other tasks in the current thread during a time.sleep interval.

Regarding the function keep_alive in your code snippet: this function cannot be made into a task because it's not declared as "async def."  Calling asyncio.sleep() from inside this type of regular function is an error; it must always be "awaited," and the "await" keyword must be inside an async def function.  On the other hand, calling time.sleep inside an async def function is *not* an error and the function will work as expected.  But it's probably not something you want to do.